# Best way to fix inconsistent csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file which is not consistent.  It looks like this where some have a middle name and some do not.  I don't know the best way to fix this.  The middle name will always be in the second position if it exists.  But if a middle name doesn't exist the last name is in the second position.

```
john,doe,52,florida

jane,mary,doe,55,texas

fred,johnson,23,maine

wally,mark,david,44,florida
```

Comment: What is exactly what you want to do? Is your python program creating this csv file? Or are you meant to fix the gap problem with your python program?

Comment: It's creating it.  I struggle with programming.  I am a a network engineer (and a good one actually) but do Python for its use and to keep my ego in check.  it doesn't come natural to me.  So I output into a text file; the output is just not consistent due to the source so I decided to make it easier for me and try to fix the flawed csv file rather than the initial parse then I could see how to back into fixing the parse. But I am open to any guidance.  My problem I think is I don't know what I don't know here.  I am trying list comprehensions. currently (still no joy)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have ① `wrong.csv` and want to produce ② `fixed.csv`.

You want to read a line from ①, fix it and write the fixed line to ②, this can be done like this

```
with open('wrong.csv') as input, open('fixed.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        line = fix(line)
        output.write(line)
```

Now we want to define the `fix` function...

Each line has either 3 or 4 fields, separated by commas, so what we want to do is splitting the line using the comma as a delimiter, return the unmodified line if the number of fields is 3, otherwise join the field 0 and the field 1 (Python counts from zero...), reassemble the output line and return it to the caller.

```
def fix(line):

    items = line.split(',')         # items is a list of strings

    if len(items) == 3:             # the line is OK as it stands
        return line

    # join first and middle name
    first_middle = join(' ')((items[0], items[1]))

    # we want to return a "fixed" line,
    # i.e., a string not a list of strings
    # we have to join the new name with the remaining info
    return ','.join([first_second]+items[2:])
```

Comment: Of course the `with …` code block can be reduced to `output.write(''.join(fix(line) for line in input))`